# Coding for when a dual-region Google Cloud Storage region goes offline?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

When using a dual-region bucket, what happens when a region goes offline?

Does my app always connect to the same primary region, and if so, when that goes down, does it invisibly switch to the secondary region?

What happens when the primary is down, a change is made to a blob in the secondary but there are also unsynchronized changes pending for that same blob that will conflict when the primary comes back online?

Or is it simply that when it's down, it's down, but my data is safe in case of total regional destruction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What happens when the primary is down, a change is made to a blob in
> the secondary but there are also unsynchronized changes pending for
> that same blob that will conflict when the primary comes back online?

*With this new option, you write to a single dual-regional bucket without having to manually copy data between primary and secondary locations. No replication tool is needed to do this and there are no network charges associated with replicating the data, which means less overhead for you storage administrators out there. **In the event of a region failure, we transparently handle the failover and ensure continuity for your users and applications accessing data in Cloud Storage**.*

[Cloud Storage updates bring new replication options](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/storage-data-transfer/store-it-analyze-it-back-it-up-cloud-storage-updates-bring-new-replication-options)

When the failure condition is corrected, pending changes will be synchronized.

Comment: Thank you. Presumably, unlike at least one Azure service I have worked with, Google's design means there simply isn't the case where an unreplicated write to object 1 in (downed) region A can conflict with another write to object 1 in secondary region B, when A comes back online.